# Micro SD is card is not working after formatting

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, pi-zero

I formatted my SD card to install the Raspbian Jessie, using Etcher, but it gave me several errors, and after that my Mac, or Windows, laptop is not detecting the card at all.

[image: Screenshot of SD card error]
What can I do with it?

Comment: You can try using win32 disk imager (PC) or dd (Mac & Linux) to burn the image to your card. What do you mean by "my Mac or Windows laptop is not detecting the card at all"? Your PC will only recognize a small FAT partition, not the entire card, and I believe the same is true on a Mac. On your Pc does it show up in  Disk Manager?

Comment: Before formatting, I was able to see the content. Now when I click, it says "Please Insert a disk into USB Drive".
Yes, I can see it under Disk Management but when I click on the properties, I see zero capacity.

Comment: @Steve - Added the screenshot, please help.

Comment: You didn't answer my question about disk management? If it shows up there you may be able to reformat the disk and start again.

Comment: Also when using drive formatting/partitioning tools - **be damn sure you are working on the device you think you are working on!** Whilst, as a GNU/Linux user I do not mind when someone formats over their Windows system drive _too_ much ( 8-] ) it can really ruin ruin your day to find you have trashed your PCs Operating System rather than the contents of a misbehaving SD Card plugged into a reader...!

Comment: I had a similar problem as this, it was fixed by using the SD card formatter: https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/

Answer (score 0):

When you install Raspbian on an SD CARD, it creates two partitions :

A FAT16 partition and an EXT4 partition

Normally you should be able to see the FAT16 partition so I guess the card is a bit damaged

You can use a third party software to format your SD card like AOMEI Partition Assistant [Download here](http://www.aomeitech.com/download.html) on Windows or GPARTED on a Linux Distrubution

Comment: Thank you, buddy, tried it but looks like my SD card is damaged. :/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like its a windows,

and you should format the card before you go. here is the hard one (hard formatting)

so;
**start menu > run > diskpart > list disk**

console show you disks available on your pc generally disk 0 is local disks (C:,D: etc) and disk 1 points to others like usb flash disk sd card vs

continue with comands

**select disk 1 > list disk > clean > create partition primary > assign letter g:**

I recommend to you to list disk again before clean command to check disk 1 is selected (you can see the exact sizes on list so you can understand which one is your sd card and which should be selected)
so you have done with the cleaning stuff and assigned the card as g: as a virtual drive you can chose any letters that does not stands for any other virtual drive

finally;

**format fs=ntfs**

ntfs can be eighter fat32 etc.

to summerize completely you need this commands in order;

**start menu > run > diskpart > list disk > select disk 1 > list disk > clean > create partition primary > assign letter g: > format fs=ntfs**

it takes nearly 20 mins to ntfs format 16gb micro-sd card for my raspberry pi 3

Comment: Thank you, buddy, tried it but looks like my SD card is damaged. :/

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot any Linux Live distro that has GParted.
2. Delete SD partition-table.
   For Pete's sake be 100% sure you are working on the SD-card and not your HDD or SSD
3. Use dd to overwrite the first 25 MBs of your **card (not card partitions)** with data from:

   /dev/urandom

And be 100% sure your **dd** is done to, and from, the right devices. If not, you could kill your Windows OS, or even harm your computer.

Comment: The OP stated on every comment that it's SD Card is broken. B.t.w. using `/dev/random` takes a very long time to gather random numbers on a RasPi. You can use `/dev/urandom` or better `/dev/zero` for just cleaning up the storage.

Comment: Well.. Who knows? I've repaired "broken" cards several times simply by destroying partition tables ++ with random data... I never said he should use the PIs random data generator...

Answer (score 0):

This might seem a little nieve, but I just inserted my unusable SD card into my digital camera, and it seemed to reformat it to a condition where I could proceed with another partitioning.  You also might want to use the minipartion disk tool on windows or the SD card formatter (https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/index.html) to just put one big FAt32 partiton on the card before other Linux partitioning.
Good luck.

Comment: The OP stated on every comment that it's SD Card is broken.

Answer (score 0):

check in file explorer with which letter (that C:// or D://, don't know what it's called) it starts and make sure windows recognizes it. and you need not format the card as it has binary junk because the OS is only installed on it. OS installation removes the formatting.

Comment: The question states that the card doesn't appear in Explorer, therefore it isn't possible to check C: or D:.